# SQL reader multiple result not return all rows

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I fetch multiple results from a query and write them into a `.CSV` file. The problem is the query returns 1700 rows, but this code only wrote 1300 rows to the file. For example, I missing rows 1301 to 1700. I wonder what the problem with this code is:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = exportCmd.ExecuteReader())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exportFilename))
{
    string Separator = ",";

    while (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < reader.FieldCount; columnCounter++)
            {
                if (columnCounter > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(Separator);
                }

                writer.Write(reader.GetValue(columnCounter).ToString());
            }

            writer.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }

        reader.NextResult();
    }

    writer.Dispose();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Creating you own export tool? Have you tried `bcp.exe` first?

Comment: I did and worked, but in the end of process, I do some logic for the result. So I need create it by my self.

Comment: instead of writing everything myself, I would delegate the export part to `bcp` or anything equivalent, calling it from my code, and then implement the custom processing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @RogerWolf, do you have any recommended link to follow?

Comment: ***WHY*** re-invent that CSV export wheel yet again?? Just use a ready-made component, like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) and stop writing code that's been written so many times already!

Comment: Bookmarked for the next journey, thanks @marc_s

Comment: how many results (not rows) is returned ?

Comment: quite big @Thorarins, even SSMS got hang when I try to see that. I smell something fishy on that too.

Comment: i think there might be something like you missing the first row on each following result , try make a do while loop instead (initiated with a read outside the loop)

Comment: not work either, I missing rows 1301 to 1700.

Comment: yeah i noticed a real problem, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your results doesnt return any rows, thats why you are missing rows, the outer while (reader.HasRows) exits without checking for next result.

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = exportCmd.ExecuteReader())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exportFilename))
    {
        string Separator = ",";

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < reader.FieldCount; columnCounter++)
                {
                    if (columnCounter > 0)
                    {
                        writer.Write(Separator);
                    }

                    writer.Write(reader.GetValue(columnCounter).ToString());
                }

                writer.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            }


            While(reader.NextResult() && !reader.hasrows)
            {
// might be a bette way to do this , problem is that one of your result has no rows, then it exits...
            }

        }

        writer.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SqlDataReader.IsDBNull` to check whether the column is null, and removed redundant data read as Yosi Dahari mentioned.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = exportCmd.ExecuteReader())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exportFilename))
{
    string Separator = ",";                        
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < reader.FieldCount; columnCounter++)
        {
            if (columnCounter > 0)                              
                writer.Write(Separator);

            if (reader.IsDBNull(columnCounter))
                writer.Write(string.Empty);
            else 
                writer.Write(reader.GetValue(columnCounter).ToString());                                                                        
        }
        writer.WriteLine(string.Empty);
    }                                                
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

Based on your code i removed all unnecessary lines of code.
As others already said, you were skipping some lines because of this `reader.NextResult();`
Further more, you dont have to dispose a reader/writer while you are in a Using-block

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = exportCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exportFilename))
        {
          string Separator = ",";
          while (reader.Read())
          {
            for (int columnCounter = 0; columnCounter < reader.FieldCount; columnCounter++)
            {
              if (columnCounter > 0)
              {
                writer.Write(Separator);
              }
              writer.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(columnCounter).ToString());
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please *explain* in a paragraph or two **what** you did, and how this fixes the issue?